# ssl error with jupyter notebook even after adding ssl key

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, jupyter-notebook

I started a jupyter notebook in a ubuntu machine. i created a password and added to the configuration file. I also created ssl using the following command

```
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mykey.key -out mycert.pem
```

Even after adding this, when i am trying to connect from a different machine, i am getting "Your connection is not private" in google chrome.
[image: Chrome]

Comment: I have a similar problem - did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: unfortunately no.